# how to pass multiple table data to view in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, arrays, eloquent, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I have 3 tables in database,

### --User

### --Profile

### --Education

User model

```
 public function profiledetails()
{
        return $this->hasOne('App\Profiledetails');
}

public function educationHasOne()
{
        return $this->hasOne('App\Education');
}
```

Profiledetails model

```
public function user()
{
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

Education model

```
public function user()
{
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

I am able to store the data.

I would like to view all table data in to one single webpage
I  use the below code to make that happen.

```
  public function index()
 {
 $user = Auth::user()->id;
 $profile = array(
     User::find($user)->profiledetails,
     User::find($user)->educationHasOne 
 );
 return view('profile.index', ['profile' => $profile]);
}
```

When is use dd($variablename),  I am able to see all required field I needed,

Now, I would like to know how to pass all this data to view in single page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass an array to the view, like so:

```
return view('profile', ['profile' => $profile]);
```

In the view, you can access `$profile`.

If you need this data for each, it's recommend to use `view composers`. Nice documentation + examples can you find here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/views#passing-data-to-views

Comment: Thanks for quick answer, I tried the above code. I get 2 errors  `ErrorException Trying to get property of non-object`. As my $profile has all values why this is not workin `return view('index',compact('profile')`

Comment: You miss a `)`. Please post your full code in your question. My answer is right, but I think it goes wrong while consolidating.

Comment: Passing an array to view works perfect. I was not able to see result as my view is bounded if user is logged-in                                                                   `public function index()
  {
     
     $user = Auth::user()->id;
     $profile   = User::find($user)->profiledetails;
     
       $education = User::find($user)->educationHasOne;
    return view('profile.index',['profile' => $profile, 'education' => $education]);
             
             
            
            
               
    
  
    
  }`

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the `view composer` part.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @Schellingerht, passing an array to the view work perfectly.

The code works perfect when user is logged in .

Below is my code

```
pass an array to the view

public function index()
{

 $user = Auth::user()->id;
 $profile   = User::find($user)->profiledetails;

 $education = User::find($user)->educationHasOne;
 return view('profile.index',['profile' => $profile, 'education' => $education]);
```

}

Comment: Perfect! ;-) If you need some data for every view, take a look at view composers.

Answer (score 0):

you can use @Schellingerht answer or even use "compact"

```
$profile= 'someVar';
return view( 'profile',compact('profile') );
```

Here you dont need to create an assoc array. Just be sure that the variable name is the same as the string in compact.
in your view you just call it with

```
{{$profile}}
```